# How to display date in one line?

Tags: view, datetime64

I have a minor problem with viewing one variable in a table. I changed data type of "date" from *object* to *datetime64*, but now it is displayed on 2 lines.

[image]

[image]

This is the code I used.

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Is there a way to make it work on one line?

I tried to widen the "date" column, by setting up the maximum width.

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking why the dash breaks the line. In order to force a non-breaking hyphen, replace the normal "-" with this HTML entity:

```
&#8209;
```

That is also displayed as a hyphen, but it will not cause a line break.